# PHP not getting right link from path

Tags: php, html, function, xpath, simple-html-dom

Ok, so I have literally never been so confused. As you can see I have pretty much  the same function twice here (I know that may seem stupid but it is just easier for me to read for my page when it's like this - but that isn't the point of this)

The first one goes to the link it's given (http://www.blade-edge.com/images/KSA/Flights/craft.asp?db=dunai) then follows the path to get the img src of https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBtYR.png

But the second function doesn't get the src of the image it's pointing to (which would be https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXgGm.png) but instead gets the src for a completely different image on the page http://www.blade-edge.com/images/KSA/Flights/prev.png.

I am sure this is a really stupid mistake that I have just overlooked but I can't work it out.

Anyone?

```
    function getImage(){
        $page = file_get_html(getPageURL());
        $element = $page->find("html/body/div/div[1]/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/img");
        $imgLink = $element[0]->getAttribute("src");
        echo "<img id='shipImage' src='".$imgLink."'></img>";
    }

    function getMap(){
        $page = file_get_html(getPageURL());
        $element = $page->find("/html/body/div/div[1]/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/img");
        $imgLink = $element[0]->getAttribute("src");
        echo "<img id='shipMap' src='".$imgLink."'></img>";
    }
```

Comment: There are no tbody tags in the html source. Load the same file two times for two different functions is a bad design. You should rewrite your functions to take a simple_html object as parameter. So instead of loading the file twice you load it only once.

Comment: Yes there are. http://i.imgur.com/pkkgJlm.png I even right click>copy xpath the <img> tag to get the exact path but it just gets a random image instead.

Comment: I know you shouldn't really use a similar function twice but that isn't the reason it isn't working.

Comment: No there aren't, right click on the page in your browser to display the source, and you will see, the tbody tag has been (probably) automatically added by your tool to display the tree.

Comment: Well, it didn't make a difference anyway when I removed it

Comment: The problem is probably due to the span tag that is unclosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
function getImage($imageType){
    $page = file_get_html(getPageURL());
    $element = $page->find("/html/body/div/div[1]/center/table/tbody", 0)->children($imageType)->find("img");
    $imgLink = $element[0]->getAttribute("src");
    return $imgLink;
}

echo "<img id='shipImage' src='" . getImage(0) . "'></img>"; // Spacecraft image
echo "<img id='shipMap' src='" . getImage(1) . "'></img>"; // Map image
```

I won't try to guess the reason behind the problem, as I do not know the innards of the library.

Comment: Thanks alot! But how do I make it so that the ship image has an id of 'shipImage' and the map image has an id of 'mapImage'

Comment: Ok so I just reverted to using 2 similar functions so I could have separate Ids. It's working fine now. One more thing though, if you look at this one (http://www.blade-edge.com/images/KSA/Flights/craft.asp?r=true&db=meeny) it has 2 map images, how do I get the source of both of them. Doesnt matter if they have same id

Comment: For cases when there are 2(map) images, instead of using $element[0], you should probably loop through the results with a foreach. To be clear - the code for getting the images would still apply, you would just need to parse the response you get in the $element differently.